# Generating dart file with json_serializable package

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, json-serialization

According to the json_serializable package [installing instructions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable#-installing-tab-), you should add the following dependency:

```
dependencies:
  json_serializable: ^2.0.3
```

This is my code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

Now running this in Flutter:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Or this for a Dart project:

```
pub run build_runner build
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find package "build_runner". Did you forget to add a dependency?

What's wrong?

Comment: You forgot to install `build_runner` you can do it by using `pub global activate build_runner` to do it globally or like you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a problem with how Pub is set up to automatically generate the installation instructions. Here are the dependencies that you actually need to add:

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
```

This is shown in the `json_serializable` [example](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/tree/master/example).

Now you can generate the dart file for a class like this

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

by running this in a Flutter project:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

or this in a Dart project:

```
pub run build_runner build
```

#### Other notes:

- Make sure that `part 'person.g.dart'` matches the name of your `person.dart` model class file. That is, don't call it `example.g.dart`.

Comment: This worked for me. Is there any shortcut for that 'flutter packages pub run build_runner build' command in Android Studio by any chance?

Comment: @FranMarzoa, I'm not sure. I used to use Android Studio for everything but I switched to VS Code and the command line more. Overall I prefer it. https://medium.com/flutter-community/moving-to-visual-studio-code-from-android-studio-a-guide-for-flutter-developers-8ce506406faf?sk=6c0843b0aadaff59fddb4945a11889e2

Answer (score 0):

you need to run
`flutter packages get`
first

Comment: The problem wasn't that I hadn't gotten the packages, but that I hadn't included `build_runner` and `json_annotation` in the pubspec.yaml file.